# Most Trophies won by a Player in T20 leagues

Tags: cricket, trivia, statistics, awards

There are so many T20 leagues played all over the World. Many T20 specialist Players like Chris Gayle, Darren Sammy, Russel, Thisara Perera, etc play almost many of them.

Which player has a record of winning **most** Trophies in T20 Leagues? (The Leagues I am interested about are IPL, BPL, BBL, MSS, PSL,Caribbean League)

Comment: I must say, it's *andre russell*.

Answer (score 2):

The player who has a record of winning most trophies in T20 Leagues is **Kieron Pollard – 11 trophies**, you can get a **list of other players in this website** (https://www.sportskeeda.com/cricket/5-most-successful-t20-cricketers-ever/5)

 Website shows *Kieron Pollard – 10* trophies because they haven't added **IPL 2017**.